# How do you disable the hyperlink warning in excel (Office 365)

Tags: excel, office365, registry

I have tried the registry edit here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-disable-hyperlink-warnings-for-office-365/9e96cae1-0960-4f20-898c-440cafd6cf7c

. I notice that my decimal 1 always reverts back to hexidecimal when I close. Upon restart nothing changes when  I try to open the hyperlink in excel.

Answer (score 3):

0 and 1 are exactly the same decimal and Hex, see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/problem-with-regedit-fail-trying-to-modify-dword/c6cdf515-c517-4196-8d4a-582e942f9315) and [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal.html)

The solution that is described in the link above (adding `DisableHyperlinkWarning` to the win registry) might not always work.

**This solution should stop hyperlink warnings in Excel for Office 365:**

Download Procmon (a monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time process/thread activity):
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

1. Run Procmon.exe
2. Toggle Capture Events to off (File > Capture Events)
3. Clear the current events (Edit > Clear Display)
4. Toggle Capture Events on.
5. Click the desired hyperlink in Excel.
6. Turn Capture Events off.
7. Filter by Process=EXCEL.EXE (Filter > Filter, chose "Process" from the list, set field to "is", type "EXCEL.EXE" in the empty field, chose "Include" from the list and click "Add".)
8. Filter also by Operation=RegQueryValue and Result=NAME NOT FOUND
9. Find the first entry with "EditFlags" in the path (use the search icon to search the filtered list or CTRL+F)
10. Right click on that entry and select > Jump to (opens registry)
    9 Add a new DWORD type named EditFlags with the hexadecimal value 10000.

In my case it was the key `htmlfile_FullWindowEmbed`

Modified from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/45364ac3-6289-4d46-99a4-2b4486db10fd/how-do-you-disable-hyperlink-warning-message-in-excel-2010-windows-7-professional-64bit?forum=w7itprosecurity&ppud=4)

Answer (score 0):

Is it changing back after restarting? if so, maybe you have some policy on your PC.

**EDIT**:
"The option to switch between the two is purely to allow entry in either format, it is always stored in Hex and for convenience the Decimal value is shown in brackets afterward in the field view

Selecting either option would have absolutely no effect on the program accessing the value and is the same either way."

Answer from here -> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problem-with-regedit-fail-trying-to-modify-dword/c6cdf515-c517-4196-8d4a-582e942f9315

Comment: Even without restarting it reverts. That is an interesting link, given that, I have no idea why it still is not working.

Comment: Is it possible there are policies on your PC?  you an see here how to check.
[link](https://www.howtogeek.com/116184/how-to-see-which-group-policies-are-applied-to-your-pc-and-user-account/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use Outlook. For example, if you want to cancel the reminder when opening the embedded pptx file, you can send yourself an email with the pptx file attachment in Outlook. After receiving it, double-click the attachment to open it, and a dialog box will pop up. The following There is a check box, "Always ask before opening this type of file", uncheck it, click Open, and there will be no warning when the embedded link of this type of file is opened in ppt or excel. This method also works for other types of files. There are some settings between office components that are related to each other.